# c++ initial value of global array declarer vs initial value of local function array declarer

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, c++17, static-initialization

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int a[100]; // <--

int main() {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

After declaring the array globally in the above code, all the indices get the value **0**.
What is the reason for this?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a[100]; // <--

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After declaring the array inside the main function in the above code and printing the values of all the indices of the array, the **garbage values** at all the indices are found.

In competitive programming I have seen many declare arrays globally in their code. But I don't understand the exact reason

Comment: Global means outside the function, local means inside the function

Comment: _@asif_ _" I have seen many declare arrays globally in their code"_ Don't adopt that behavior please, it lowers your chances for serious learning of the language, and getting a good job at the software development industry a lot.

Comment: Note that you can write `int a[100] {};` anywhere, and it will always be cleared. Why bother with the other rukes?

Comment: *In competitive programming I have seen many declare arrays globally in their code* -- I've also seen many declare arrays of one million elements, just because the question states there could be up to a million elements.  If you show up at an interview writing code like that, I can bet you will not be hired.

Answer (score 3):

If a variable declaration does not have an explicit initializer specified, and is not (part of) a `class`/`struct` type whose constructor initializes its data, then the variable gets default-initialized to zeros at compile-time only when it is declared in global or static scope, whereas it is not default-initialized to anything at all when declared in local scope.